# WP_REST_Request "set_query_params" - $_GET is empty

Tags: php, wordpress, get, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to create a WP_REST_Request and set some query parameters. I have set it like so:

```
$request = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/v2/some-path');
$request->set_query_params( ['lang' => 'da'] );
```

However, the parameters are not set. If I return just the $_GET parameters from the requested route, then it returns an empty array. How come?

I have followed this guide: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_request/set_query_params/

This is my whole code:

```
$request = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/v2/some-path');
$request->set_query_params( ['lang' => 'da'] );
$response = rest_do_request( $request );
$server = rest_get_server();
$data = $server->response_to_data( $response, false );
```

If I run `get_query_params` it get the correct result.

```
$request->get_query_params(); // it returns ['lang' => 'da']
```

Answer (score 0):

In my register_rest_route I have to fetch $_GET parameters like so:

```
register_rest_route( 'jwr/v1', '/products/(?P<slug>\S+)', array(
  'methods' => 'GET',
  'callback' => function($data) {
    $_GET = $data->get_query_params(); // this part fetches the right $_GET params
```